# Create Add ins for Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I am a C#.NET developer now i am assigned to develop add ins for Microsoft Dynamics CRM, but i have no idea on it. I also google to get steps for creating sample hello world add ins for dynamics CRM and import that add ins into CRM, but i did not found and suitable links.
  so, please help me to share some links to created add ins for Microsoft dynamics CRM. I assigned for create the below mentioned add ins.

- Social Media connector (Facebook, LinkedIn, twitter, etc.)
- Google map with marker indicate the service person availability
- Record clone for entity level

  Please share some idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Social media connector rather than writing it yourself look at "Parrot"
http://www.webfortis.com/webfortis-social-media-solutions.aspx

Even if you do end up writing it yourself this should give you a good understanding of how CRM and social media can work.

Unless you have to use Google Maps I would hold off until the release of "Orion" or CRM 2013 as this has Bing Maps functionality provided out of the box.

As for "Record clone for entity level" I would suggest that you look at "Plugins" for CRM as this will give you an understand of how to do different tasks with C# and Dynamics CRM.

Add ins (UI changes) are done using "Customizations" you create your own Solution with different Entities in it. A video like the following will show you the basics of Entity creation

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2wL44EfrpG8

Answer (score 0):

Start by downloading and reviewing the sample code in the [SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004)

Comment: SDK have sample for plugins only, not have Add ins ( UI design)